# Netbeans with gradle plugin runs all tests when build running

Tags: netbeans, gradle, gradle-plugin

When I run the build command in netbeans with the gradle plugin, all the tests run and the build fails if any of them fail. How can I change this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If build action is bind to `build` task then this is expected behavior. You can modify your project to execute something like `assemble` or `jar` when build action is invoked. `build` depends on `test` while those others don't and they still build enough for you to execute the application.